# How To Deep Test a React Component

Tags: reactjs

I would like to be able to deep test a react component instead of shallow test it. With all the talk of shallow testing I can't find how to do this. To confirm I have the component...

Inside `App` is a child component called `Child`. Inside `Child` I call `this.setState({name:'blah'})`.

In my test I want to do this...

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
var renderedAppComponent = ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
expect(renderedAppComponent.childComponment.state.name).toBe('hello world');
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at storybook and I think it's story shots, where you can check what it renders?

Comment: so mock childComponent as an object with a spied `setState()` and ensure it gets called correctly? else, testing internal state is probably pointless. test that Child will react to whatever and set its state separately. don't make coupling you don't need to. **but yes, you can have a ref on the parent component to the child one and read the child one's state.**

Comment: No I don't want to mock the child. I want to build the entire chain (a bit like a snapshot). Except I don't want to dig around in the snapshot, I want to look at the actual state of each component. Yes - it's coupled like a snapshot, and thus will be easier for me to check the entire thing and make sure the components are interacting properly....